# Unable to assign a global LB IP to the Ingress-Nginx Helm Chart

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, ingress-nginx

I am attempting to assign a static global LB IP in GCP to an ingress controller (Ingress-Nginx) in GKE but whenever I do so I get an error message regarding

```
Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: requested ip "<IP_ADDRESS>" is neither static nor assigned to the LB
```

If I attempt to set that LB IP value to a static regional IP that is in the same region as my cluster it works. If I don't pass in a LB IP value that also works and an IP is assigned to me.

I am using the command

`helm install ingress-nginx --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="<IP_ADDRESS>" ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx`

Is there an additional `set` flag that I am not using or does my GKE cluster need to be in more than 1 region?

Answer (score 2):

This was due to assigning a global IP to the ingress controller. It should use a regional IP instead of a global one.